# Refresh values from external sheet on background

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets, where I need to refresh values (function VLOOKUP) from source.xlsm to update.xlsm ON BACKGROUND by VBA (only manual refresh by button with assigned macro - I do not want to use update button in Excel options).

I have found two codes, which complete this task, however, the source.xlsm always pops up for a second while the task is made. I would like to have the task completed without the source file being visible on the screen.

Any ideas?

```
Sub Read_External_Sheet()

    '''''Define Object for Target Workbook
    Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Source_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Target_Path As String

    '''''Assign the Workbook File Name along with its Path
    '''''Change path of the Target File name
    Target_Path = "D:\Source.xlsm"
    Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Target_Path)
    Set Source_Workbook = ThisWorkbook

    '''''With Target_Workbook object now, it is possible to pull any data from it
    '''''Read Data from Target File
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
    DoEvents
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = Target_Data
    DoEvents

    '''''Update Target File
    Source_data = Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 1)
    DoEvents
    Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1) = Source_data
    DoEvents

    '''''Close Target Workbook
    Target_Workbook.Close False

    '''''Process Completed
    MsgBox "SHEET UPDATED"

End Sub


Sub Read_External_Sheet_2()
Dim FName As Workbook
With Application
.EnableEvents = False
Set FName = .Workbooks.Open("D:\Source.xlsm", False)
mybook = FName.Name
With FName
.RefreshAll
.Close True 'save file
End With
.EnableEvents = True
End With
msg = MsgBox(mybook & " Refreshed")
End Sub
```

Comment: Well done pnuts! Solved! Thank you for your help!